# How to differentiate between an old instantiated object and a new one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 public void PlaceIconToSlot() //gets called by a button
{ 
    GameObject IconClone = Instantiate(Icons[properIconIndex], Slots[properSlotIndex].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Icons and Slots are Arrays. The first one tells the program what to instantiate and the second one where to instantiate. Quaternion.identity just means no rotation.

What I am trying to do: Duplicate an image and place it in a slot, then if another image is placed on top of the old one, the old one should be destroyed.

What is happening: Everything works, except that the old one doesn't get destroyed and the new one sits on top of the old. I mean of course it doesn't get destroyed since I didn't program that, but this is my question. How can I Destroy(OldClone) when there is only an IconClone? How can I introduce to the function the concept of an OldClone?

Comment: You could always keep track of the old IconClones...

Answer (score 2):

Since you call the function `PlaceIconToSlot` I'd guess, you might have a `Slot` component. If so, you can add a member variable to it that holds the current icon (assuming it's one icon per slot) and just work with that.

Something like this:

```
public class Slot
{
    public GameObject Icon;

    public void PlaceIconToSlot()
    {
        // If you overwrite it, the garbage collector will destroy it a some point anyways,
        // but it doesn't hurt to do this destroy call
        Destroy(Icon);    
        Icon = Instantiate(...);
    }
}
```

Potentially pass the parameters (the new icon to instantiate) to this function if you above function at some centralized spot. Something like `SpotXYZ.PlaceIcon(icon)` or `SpotXYZGameObject.GetComponent<Slot>().PlaceIcon(icon)`.

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to set a tag (let's say `oldImage`) to your original image. When you instantiate, destroy the object with that tag and then add the `oldImage` tag to the new image so that it will then be destroyed when another image is instantiated.

```
public void PlaceIconToSlot() //gets called by a button
{ 
    GameObject IconClone = Instantiate(Icons[properIconIndex], Slots[properSlotIndex].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("oldImage"));
    IconClone.gameObject.tag="oldImage";
}
```

I haven't tried this but it's worth a go!